# How to type Express query parameters with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, express

I type all my middleware functions as

```js
express.RequestHandler<
  { /* route params */ },
  { /* response body */ },
  { /* request body */ },
  { /* query params */ }
>
```

and then I pass them as an array to the respective route handler, e.g.

```js
const getHandler: [RequestHandler<...>, RequestHandler<...>] = [(req, res, next) => {...}, (req, res, next) => {...}]
app.get("/", getHandler)
```

This works fine for most of my routes, except one specific route where my RequestHandler looks like this:

```
RequestHandler<{}, {}, {}, { [key: string]: string | undefined }>
```

I'm typing it like this because I don't care about the exact property names and just want to narrow down the default type of `string | ParsedQs | string[] | ParsedQs[] | undefined` to `string | undefined`. For some reason this throws an error though:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '[RequestHandler<{}, {}, {}, { [key: string]: string | undefined }, Record<string, any>>]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Application'.ts(2769)
```

Weirdly enough, when I spread the array in the route controller like this: `app.get("/", ...getHandler)` it works and doesn't throw an error anymore. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Weird, it seems like express has wrong type definitions. If you look at type signature of `get`, you will see that `...handlers` arguments should be an array of `RequestHandlerParams<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals>`, which in turn can be `RequestHandler<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals>` or `Array<RequestHandler<P>>`. I'm not sure why they didn't include the rest of type arguments in this last array definition, this is what's causing the error. I think you'll have to spread, maybe open an issue in `@types/express`

Comment: Correction: I shouldn't say "wrong type definitions", more like "inconsistent". Because technically this `get` function should not be generic at all, because you never know what a client will send you in the body and query. But since they decided to make it generic, I don't see why they didn't put the rest of type arguments in this `Array<RequestHandler<P>>`

Comment: @AlexChashin I found a possibly related PR: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/56124 - do you think this fixes this issue?